# What is the easiest way to determine which parameter is causing exceptions?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# function that persists data to SQL-server through a stored procedure with a little more than 100 parameters. (Yes, I know, that's probably not a good design, but legacy code and lets not get into that here.) ;-)

For some reason this code now comes up with this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
  Message=Error converting data type int to tinyint.
```

Now, I've taken a first look down the parameter- and variable-pairs, and there is no obvious culprit. (The parameters are of many datatypes, not just tinyint)

So what is the fastest way to determine the rogue variable? And does anybody know of a good way to either handle this proactively, by making the c#-side verify the variable against the parameter at run-time - or somehow extending the error message to tell exactly which parameter is failing?

Implementing an ORM is not an option at this stage.

---

Edit: I've started writing a function `CheckParameters` that will initially loop through the parameters and simply list the parameters and the corresponding value. I'm thinking it could be extended with actual knowledge of the different datatypes, but for now I just want it to aid in finding the bad variable.

Structure is as follows:

```
        try
        {
            cmdStat.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
         CheckParameters(cmdStat.Parameters);   
         //re-throw 
        } 

        private void CheckParameters(SqlParameterCollection parameterCollection)
        {
          foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameterCollection)
          {
            Trace.Write("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", parameter.ParameterName, parameter.DbType, parameter.SqlDbType, parameter.Value);
          }            
        }
```

Comment: Just an idea, you could set default values to the parameters in the stored procedure, then try to remove some of your coded input parameters, till the error disappears.

Comment: Have you tried using [DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) to ensure that you have the correct parameter list?  Then it is only a matter of getting the values right.

Comment: @user92546 Actually, I was just going down that path. I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Are you building the parameter list "by hand"?  If so, you may be using a datatype that doesn't match the sproc's definition.  `DeriveParameters` should give you the `Parameters` collection with all of the datatypes set and move any conversion errors to the C# side of the C#/SQL interface.

Comment: As I see it, the problem with introducing DeriveParameters, which is a good idea and could also be good general practice, is that when the existing code has Parameters.AddWithValue, this will give you double up in the Parameters collection.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is replace the proc with a stub.

Then I'd binary chop half the parameters to be long enough to cope with int. If the error went away I'd binary chop only half, and check again. If the error didn't go away then I'd do the other half.

I suspect it would take at max less than 10 attempts to find it.

Comment: I see your idea, but that doesn't really scale. At the very least, there are 10 sprocs like this or similar.

Comment: A journey of thousand miles begins with a single step.